# Rotman: Examples of identifications that are not homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity, quotient-spaces

I'm working through Rotman's Algebraic Topology, and he defines an identification as a map this is continuous and an open mapping, i.e. $f: X \to Y$ is an identification if $U$ is open in $Y$ if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. He then goes on to prove corollary 1.10 that gives a way of constructing a homeomorphism from an identification.

Identifications seem like such nice maps to me that I can't think of a good example of one that is not a homeomorphism. Having such an example would help make this corollary more concrete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that what Rotman is calling an identification is often called a *quotient map*, which are maps that we typically think of as "identifying" points of some space to get a new space. Other examples of quotient maps that are not homeomorphisms are

1. The quotient map $\Bbb R^{n+1}\smallsetminus\{0\}\to\Bbb R\Bbb P^n$, where $\Bbb R\Bbb P^n$ is real projective $n$-space. This isn't a homeomorphism because the projective space is actually compact, while the punctured Euclidean space is not.
2. The quotient map that identifies corresponding points in two copies of $\Bbb R$ except for their origins. The resulting space is known as *the line with two origins* and it isn't Hausdorff, though the domain is Hausdorff.
3. The quotient space where we identify two points $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$ if and only if $\alpha-\beta$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$ is homeomorphic to the circle, but it isn't homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ because again the circle is compact while $\Bbb R$ is not.
4. The quotient map that identifies all points in a given space. The resulting space is a singleton, which is seldom homeomorphic to the original space.

Comment: these are great, thank you.

Comment: Hi AOrtiz, I want to learn some algebraic topology too. Could you recommend some good text that you use to learn ?

Comment: @Sou Hi Sou. I would recommend starting with Munkres' book *Topology* or Allen Hatcher's book *Algebraic Topology*. The book by Hatcher is made available for free online by the author here: https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf. John Lee's book *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* also has a lot of good material on algebraic topology including covering spaces and homology, and it's written in the same great style as his *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

Comment: Thanks. I like Munkres' books. I found Hatcher's a bit difficult to read, but seems like everyone like Hatcher's, so probably it's just my background then. Thanks anyway. Great examples btw (+1). And yes i love Lee's of course.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, by thinking a bit more carefully, I have an idea: $I \times I$ is the unit square, $h$ is an identification that takes the square to a cylinder $C$ by mapping both the top and bottom edges to the same part of the cylinder, which causes $h$ to not be a bijection. By modding these two edges together in the quotient space we then get a homeomorphism from $I \times I \: / \sim \to C$ simply because we made $h$ bijective.

Comment: Note that making $h$ a bijection does not automatically mean you get a homeomorphism--a continuous bijection does not have to be a homeomorphism in general.  It is automatic though when the domain is compact and the codomain is Hausdorff, which is the case here.

Comment: So being an identification doesn't necessarily mean its inverse is continuous? Is it only on one side (right inverse $h \circ h^{-1}$)?